# Display a button only when a session variable is set in Flask

Tags: flask

I have a single page in Flask App where I am ftping a file from other server depending on the user's IP. Now, I want to display a download file button only after I have ftped the file, basically when `session['file']` is set. How can I achieve that?

Comment: are you downloading the file in your endpoint and then rendering the template, or you want to achieve polling (when file is downloaded at your server) to show download button

Comment: I am using ajax to handle client server so there's no render template, I want to poll for session variable if that's possible.

Comment: instead polling for session variable which is not persistent data, better approach would be using saving the state of the downloaded file in db(key/value storage like redis). you can then have a endpoint which serves the status of the requested file, this way you can alter visibility even after session gets destroyed